# Is least square error related to mean square error

Tags: regression, terminology, linear

Linear regression:
**Is below 2 same -**

1. (least squares error) divided by number of data points
2. MSE Mean Square Error.

Here 1 is used to figure out the regression line.
     2 is used as evaluation metrix of the same line.(Of course RMSE is better one)

I know Least Square Error is used to BUILD the model
       MSE is used to EVALUATE the model

For me, Mean Square Error = Least Square Error divided by N
This is where I am confused. We are same kind of calculation for BUILDING and EVALUATING. Of course, this should not be case. I need an explanation on both these terms.
 On the whole, Mean Square Error can be calculated using LEAST Square Error mathematically or NOT.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that using the same kind of metric to build and evaluate the model shoult "of course, [...] not be the case"?

Comment: just like to know one thing..
Is minimum least square error is equal to Mean square error.
Mathematically, both are calculated based on diff in actual and prediction of Y. The diff is squared in both the cases. Then how come MSE can be used as evaluation metrix.

Comment: It is only a potential pitfall if you train the model and evaluate the model using the same set of data. In order to properly evaluate the model you should look at using cross validation, using training data to train the model and a separate test data to evaluate the model.

Comment: Thank you Morgan, So if we MSE in building the model, we don't use that in evaluation. perfect. Alternatively, we can pick cross validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say yourself, we evaluate the performance of a linear regression with the (R)MSE. Surely, when we start with our regression analysis, we will want to maximise the performance of our analysis. So what we do is create an objective function that maximises the performance.

Maximising performance in linear regression means minimising the (R)MSE. So we try to find regression coefficients $\beta$ that minimise the MSE:

\begin{eqnarray} 
\arg\min_{\beta} MSE = \arg \min_{\beta} \underbrace{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}(y - X\beta)^2}_{MSE}
= \arg \min_{\beta} \underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}(y - X\beta)^2}_{\text{sum of least squares}}
\end{eqnarray}

As you suspected, minimising the `MSE` and `sum of least squares` result in the same solution and may therefore be seen as equivalent.

Comment: def train_test_rmse(feature_cols):
    X = bikes[feature_cols]
    y = bikes.total
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=123)
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
    return np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))

So in the above method., 
we are evaluating model based on the metrix RMSE. Right?

Comment: I dont know about your code.. I guess so